# Format string to alternate between fixed and scientific form, in order to show n digits at most

Tags: python, formatting

I've difficulties to master the `g` [format for floats](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). I'm trying to find a format which shows 2 figures at most. This requires to switch from `f` to `e` according to the magnitude.

My constraints are:

- No change to configuration files
- No non-significant zeros
- No extra spaces (I've used width in the example below, but this is just for the question).
- If possible replace default `1.99e00` by `1.99`.

There is `g` intended for that, but I can't find the correct combination of width and precision. I'm not skilled enough to know if there is a solution.

---

The first line are numbers to be printed, the second line is what I'm trying to get. The last is my best attempt:

```
   0.01234560    0.12345600    1.23456000   12.34560000  123.45600000 1234.56000000
     1.23e-02      1.23e-01          1.23         12.35      1.23e+02      1.23e+03 
        0.012          0.12           1.2            12       1.2e+02       1.2e+03
```

The code:

```
numbers = [1.23456 * 10**k for k in range(-2,4)]
print(*[f'{x:12.8f}' for x in numbers], sep=' ')
# Desired formatting
for x in numbers:
    if x < 1 or x > 99: print(f'{x:12.2e}', end=' ')
    else: print(f'{x:12.2f}', end=' ')
print()
# Best approximation
for x in numbers: print(f'{x:12.2g}', end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make your normal number to scientific notation
just use this:

```
name="{:e}".format(12340000)
print(name)
```

output:

```
1.234000e+07
```

Comment: I know how to format in scientific notation, please read the question: "*This requires to switch from f to e according to the magnitude.*"